# How to send post/get request from inside iframe in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I want to send a post request from inside an iframe in laravel. I have the script file (from which I'm sending the request) in a folder in public (public/scripts/subscript/main.js). And my example request looks like this in the main.js file:

```
   $.post("./server/update-data", { id: 1 }, function(data){
      console.log(data);
   }).fail(function() {
      alert("ERROR");
   });
```

//route

```
   Route::post('/server/update-data', 'PageController@goToServer');
```

The specific issue is that the request is going through the parent route then to the route given, e.g
`(localhost:8000/parent/server/update-data)`
but should look like this
`(localhost:8000/server/update-data)`

which should not be. How do I skip the parent route?

Please note that this same code works for requests that are not from inside the iFrame.

Comment: If you want URL to be `/server/update-data` then you should put that as your URL, not `./server/update-data`. VTC typo.

Comment: Also please pay attention to your tags. This is clearly a question about a client-side script requesting a URL. What's on the other end of that URL is not relevant to the question.